# Do Daleks Travel in Time?

Tags: doctor-who

Do Daleks travel in time, like Timelords?  And, if so, is there any thing to show how they pick when they're going next?  Or are they a "linear" threat that got big, were defeated, and grew back later (and repeated that cycle a number of times)?

Comment: As long as there are no time-stairs ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, they do travel through time, although in most episodes in a less sophisticated way than the Time Lords (as others, like [Time Agents](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Agency), do).

The Daleks envied the Time Lords' superior technology, and try to gain it for themselves.  In ["Remembrance of the Daleks"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562871/) (7th Doctor) the Daleks try to steal the [Hand of Omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_of_Omega), which could create a power source for (Time Lord style) time travel.

By the time of the Last Great Time War, Dalek time travel technology is perhaps as sophisticated as the Time Lords'.  In particular, in [*Doomsday*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0756450/) (10th Doctor) the Daleks are able to "emergency temporal shift" without (as far as we see) any external device, suggesting that the Dalek "travel machines" (their suits) incorporate some form of time travel device.

The Daleks sometimes use devices that create "Time Corridors" for travel rather than vessels like a TARDIS, for example:

- ["The Evil of the Daleks"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562911/) (2nd Doctor) - their device isn't very good yet, and it might not be Corridor-based, but it's similar
- ["Day of the Daleks"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562837/) (3rd Doctor) - a device that transports people (or Daleks) - it's not clear if this was a Corridor or not, but it's similar
- ["Resurrection of the Daleks"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562872/) (5th Doctor) - explicitly a Time Corridor
- ["Remembrance of the Daleks"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562871/) (7th Doctor) - explicitly a Time Corridor
- ["Victory of the Daleks"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1577258/) (11th Doctor) - the Daleks escape via a Corridor

In ["The Chase"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chase_%28Doctor_Who%29) (1st Doctor), the Daleks are using ships (Vicki stows away on one when she gets left behind by the Doctor) that can time travel.  Also with the 1st Doctor, in ["The Daleks' Master Plan"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daleks%27_Master_Plan) we see the Daleks with time-travel capable ships (but not as sophisticated as the Doctor's or the Meddling Monk's).

In terms of how their choose their destination time, it differs with each of these stories.  Generally the date and location have been chosen because they offer some opportunity to further the domination of the Daleks (sometimes, as in "The Evil of the Daleks", to improve their time travel technology and prevent anyone else having it).  Presumably they have also travelled widely throughout time on occasions where the Doctor was not around to prevent it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, Dalek Caan once used an Emergency Temporal Shift, so I presume they travel through time this way, or maybe they ships and other technology that allows them to travel through time, much like the Time Lords. That's probably why they're so dangerous and feared.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything that the existing (accepted) answer hasn't already mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

Of course they can time travel the cult of Skaro are chasing the first doctor through time , that's why he can't steer the TARDIS in  on random-mode to shake off the dalek death squads chasing him through the vortex, the daleks as a full empire are on par with the timelords in many ways , probably not temporal engineering fully but close, and they have no morals holding them back.
The daleks and davros started to get wise shortly after Tom Baker tried to stop them being born, that was the turning point of dalek temporal engineering as they were threatened by another (more brutal?) Species and so had to prove that daleks are king badass.the time lord CIA were the main reason the daleks even knew about time travel originally, arguably they doctor but he was sent by them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is "radis" supposed to be "TARDIS?"  Note that a lot of this is covered by the accepted answer, so if you're going to post a new answer you should have new examples or new sources to cite.  You might want to read [answer] and take the [tour].