# In "The Pandorica Opens", how does the alliance reach the Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

The alliance identifies the cracks in the universe to the Doctor and decides to imprison him in the Pandorica.

How does the alliance (Daleks, Cybermen, Silurians, Sontarans and others) reach 102AD?

Do all of them have time machines to get there?

Comment: It has been established that the Daleks are capable of time travel too...hence the "Time War" against the Time Lords. Probably the other guys just hitched a ride with them...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least some of these races are indeed capable of time travel:

- Daleks certainly have time machines, of varying degrees of sophistication, as described in the answer to [Do Daleks Travel in Time?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11164/do-daleks-travel-in-time)
- Cybermen were shown using a time machine in the Sixth Doctor serial [Attack of the Cybermen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_of_the_Cybermen), though it's unknown whether they retained it later
- Sontarans have also been shown using a time machine in their very first appearance, the Third Doctor serial [The Time Warrior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Warrior).

I haven't been able to find any instance of time-travelling Silurians (though they are capable of *communication* across time, if not physical travel, as shown in the Eleventh Doctor episode [The Name of the Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Name_of_the_Doctor) - thanks @Richard for catching this), but they and other races could easily have been given a free ride by other members of the alliance.

Comment: The Silurian apparently have candles(?) that are capable of allowing a conversation across time and space. Time travel doesn't seem to be outside their capabilities...; http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Name_of_the_Doctor_(TV_story)

Comment: @Richard Communication across time, not necessarily physical travel. I suppose it's worth adding though.

Comment: Maybe future Silurians contacted 102AD Silurians and told them to go get this Doctor guy

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the Silurians have cryogenic technology so they could have been awakened by one of the other races (remember, they were [the original masters of Earth](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Silurian)) when it was time for the Pandorica to be opened.

The other race at the Pandorica was the Judoon.
[From the wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Judoon): They have teleportation technology and are trained to use all known forms of transit - so they could have commandeered a time machine (especially since they're members of the Shadow Proclamation and would have the authority to do so).

Or, since they were around in early universal history, they'd definitely exist as a species in 102AD and easily be able to teleport to Earth.

---

[The Alliance](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Alliance_(The_Pandorica_Opens)) consisted of the additional races (all info from the Tardis Wiki):

- Atraxi (no time travel but intergalactic police so possibility of getting technology from another race)
- Autons (there at the time: Rory etc)
- [Blowfish](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Blowfish) show up in Torchwood having travelled through the [Cardiff space-time Rift](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Cardiff_Space-Time_Rift) so they could have arrived that way.
- Chelonians (no time travel)
- Draconians (no time travel)
- Drahvins (no time travel)
- Haemogoth (no time travel)
- Hoix (have travelled through the Cardiff Rift so time travel is possible)
- Nestene Consciousness (as with Autons)
- Roboforms (travel alongside planetary invaders and so could have hitched a time travel ride)
- Slitheen family ([have time travelled](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Slitheen_family))
- Sycorax (have teleportation so could have arrived as the Judoon did)
- Terileptils (no time travel)
- Uvodni (teleporters)
- Weevils (have travelled through the Cardiff Rift and are also time sensitive)
- Zygons (probably on Earth during that time - we wouldn't know!)